# How to remove lines while keeping individual rows visible on a tablet

Tags: lists

I have created a simple view which is a list of items and each item is seperated by a line. Shown below:

[image]

I would like to remove the lines as I think they add clutter to the screen but when I do I find the chevron and text too far apart to know which chevron to click.

The lines help keep each row distinct.

So how can I remove the lines while also keeping lines distinct?

This is more of a problem on a tablet held in Horizontal mode rather than Vertical mode as the text and chevron are further apart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on @Sergey's suggestion: you could try rebuilding your layout to:

- align your list in [multiple columns](https://www.dropbox.com/help):
  [image: Dropbox]
- think of other ways to visualise a set of links: maybe cards or tiles that could wrap horizontally? Maybe you could also get rid of the glyphs altogether?
  [image: Another dropbox]
- work as a [Split-View](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/split-views/) (this is my favourite as you get to fully use your screen with additional functionality):
  [image: iOS Human Interface Guidelines]
- UPD: somewhat outdated solution: use alternating backgrounds on your rows (aka “zebra list”):
  [image: Zebra list]

Comment: A variant of "zebra" is to alternate the backgrounds in 3-line groups.  Our eyes can distinguish top, middle, and bottom lines in such groups, but have trouble with telling apart two or more "middle" lines in a group.  Back in the old days, "computer paper" was routinely printed with alternating white/green backgrounds for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can increase left margin for lines at tablet horizontal layout. This will reduce empty space between question and chevron and will also introduce some visual hierarchy for sections.

And...

**Funny idea!**

You can try some unusual approach, let's call it "Gmail inbox". Gmail has a view where after mail Subject immediately goes letter text (visually different).

Put (visually muted) answers right after your questions. Probably some short answers like "You can't." will fit fully, other will give a user some idea about what is in the answer. And you will not need any lines, as your text will be your lines.

Of course this should appear only on huge screens, giving their users additional value instead of empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hover for the row that changes the whole rows color (lighter gradient). That's gonna make it easy to see what chevron corresponds to the text.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this is for a tablet device - so no hover behavior

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the tablet mentioned in the question.

Comment: I just edited the question to make it clearer - it slipped my mind that actually using a tablet makes a big difference to ux

Comment: Thinking about it, why not make the whole row clickable and just remove the lines outright, I think that's what's FOTM in web design right now.

Comment: Even on desktops one should not rely on hover. As a [Tridactyl](https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl) user I do not have hover on my desktop browser.

Comment: @dotancohen You're right, there are more and more of touchscreen laptops and bigger screen devices, but I just love to play with those hover animations and effects. Guess I'll just have to let them die :(